# I cannot pull branch to my local repository

Tags: eclipse, git

I want to pull branches to my local repository but I cannot. I tried revert my last commit now all remote branches like that [image]. What is '29e74ac'? Is it can be about references/HEAD ? [image].  I am using eclipse and trying from team->switch to->other when try to switch branch.

Comment: I guess I am in Detached HEAD.

Comment: In Git you _fetch_ stuff from a (remote) repository into your local repository and you _pull_ stuff from the upstream branch (_Pull_) or from another branch (_Pull..._) into the currently checked out branch. Please use the correct terms and give more details, especially the exact steps how to reproduce this issue.

Comment: And to be clear, "fetch" just updates local information about branches, it doesn't change the HEAD on your local branch or do anything else to it.  I echo the statement about using the correct terms. Git uses somewhat generic terms for specific actions, and you have to be clear on exactly what is intended.

Answer (score 0):

First, You need to go to a known branch (ex: master). Because you are not incorrect branch

```
git checkout master
```

If you are trying to pull the newly created branch, you need to fetch

```
git fetch
```

then you can see all the branches

```
git branch -a
```

Now you can check out whatever branch you want

```
git checkout branch_name
```

Then you can get pull using

```
git pull origin branch_name
```

Comment: The question is not about Git on the command line (git-core), which may not even be installed.

Comment: I can pull branches on command line, The problem about eclipse. I am getting last commit with commit id, when I try to checkout a branch from remote. I download new eclipse and figure out but Whats the problem about current eclipse.

Comment: @displayname If you are using both, Eclipse and the command line, you may have forgotten to do a refresh in Eclipse. There is no problem with the current Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me and I don't need to keep any of my local changes, I get back to the branch's last commit by running `git reset --hard HEAD`. This command resets your local repository to the HEAD (latest commit on that branch) but removes all file changes. If you need to keep changes I'd probably suggest stashing your files before that.

Comment: When what happened? Why using the command line for a reset instead of Eclipse?

Comment: Apologies, I don't use Eclipse so I wasn't sure what the options were for that. Does Eclipse have an option to Reset a branch?

Comment: Of course, Eclipse supports all three types of reset. Using the command line is less intuitive and slower here.

Comment: Okay, so instead of aggressively telling me that of course it supports it, why don't you tell the person how to do it from Eclipse?

Comment: What makes you say I would tell you that aggressively? I took time to tell you that this question is not about the command line and to answer your follow-up questions. In contrast, you haven't answered what you mean by _when this happens_ yet. Reset is a very basic function and therefore it is _of course_ supported (or can you name an editor or an IDE with Git support where reset is missing?).